# ERC1155 token does not have "send" button inside the Metamask wallet

Tags: metamask, erc-1155

I`ve found that any ERC1155 token does not have "send" button inside the Metamask wallet. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found the answear - "MetaMask does not yet support sending your ERC-1155 tokens, although we're working to implement this feature soon".